# Numerical Evaluation Error

Tags: numerics

Could anyone explain why the evaluation of this gives a weird error?

> a = 1.11111111111111111111; Do[a = 2 a - a; a, 50]
> [image]

Comment: It's `Precision[]` and its loss due to subtractive cancellation.

Answer (score 2):

In the calculation of the `Precision[]` of `2 a - a`, the error in `2 a` and `a` are treated as independent.  Therefore the error bounds, `2 Δa` and `Δa`, are added.  Thus the new error bound is estimated as `3 Δa`, and the `Precision[]` is reduced by `Log10[3]` each iteration. Therefore we run out of `Precision[]` in `Precision[a]/Log10[3]` steps:

```
a = 1.11111111111111111111;
Precision[a]/Log10[3]
```

> ```
> (*  42.014  *)
> ```

[The `a` in the image and in the supplied code seem different.]